# Access data from 2-d array from apex controller in lightning

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, controller

I wanted to access my Id field from apex controller.
[image]

```
 var getID=component.get("v.Leads");
 var getidvalue=JSON.stringify(getID);
```

I am getting the data in following form from apex controller.But here i want to access all Id fields in array.I am unable to figure out the way.
I even tried using `alert(getidvalue.Id);`

Comment: Well, `getidvalue` is an array. So if you want an `id`, you will have to access the element using an index first. Like this for example: `getidvalue[0].Id`.

Comment: @Martin.I already tried that but still didnot work out.

Comment: What do you mean by not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    getID.forEach(function(element) {//loop through array
    console.log(element.Id);//get id of each object inside array since you structure is array of objects
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(yourString);
    while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
        if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) &&
            (parser.getText() == 'Id')) {
            parser.nextToken();
            system.debug('Id=' + parser.getText());
        }
    }
```